# Is there a way to prevent clicking on a chart resulting in resetting the legend selection?

Tags: vega-lite

In this [example vega lite link](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9p3OgENCCvCFIAnADYoQYwgAdKyAPTGwdKADoAVpTqZNcNOstRMhY1H0BbY2kwICgC0isqU7pQAAmgAjJYATACclmzGoQpmCuqUNpTQIHIg3lkA1qqEAJ76mDpgcOpgmjXclHAAXjXIAGxshZhQkHQkSKg8mhDq5VWdIFAQ3iQK2tzwDnQ6APLqiCQF3AAeU9U6AI6kCkRwysT%20ICtYmuvIIIIT4foQ2JiThRVHM2cLsRrk5miBVo8dABZOBNSgAfWq6nhAHEluMoAVCuEmmBiPlRjjMHiJhwJP8dN5SJpiHcQAAjEhPEBNBD9db3NaUFAAbRAWx2mIAurJuAASShgRiYYo6PSGEx%20AIKSwIK6MUj0yxwCDGSXS4pKwJBRyETB%20FiWAAcljitny0iAA), if you select an item from the legend, and then click anywhere in the chart area, the legend selection resets.

If I use interval selection to enable panning and zooming, and I have legend items selected, the legend gets reset anytime I click to pan.

Is there anyway to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

The `bind` config can be taken as an object having the `legend` which takes configs of [Event Streams](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/event-streams/). Then, you can simply provide a unique `markname` that will trigger the click event when legend of that name is clicked and Events originating from other marks will be ignored.

Below is the given configuration or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9p3OgENCCvCFIAnADYoQYwgAdKyAPTGwdKADoAVpTqZNcNOstRMhY1H0BbY2kwICgC0isqU7pQAAmgAjJYATACclmzGoQpmCuqUNpTQIHIg3lkA1qqEAJ76mDpgcOpgmjXclHAAXjXIAGxshZhQkHQkSKg8mhDq5VWdIFAQ3iQK2tzwDnQ6APLqiCQg3E0I-euostwAHlPVOgCOpApEcMrE-nsgq5rHIIIT4foQ2JhJoUKpcZrd7sQnk5mm8sB8dABZOBNSgAfWq6lRAHEluMoAVCuEmmBiPlRiRCIC0EsAMoOTAk0E6ClUpYFFr0kkTDgSJnIIqkTTEV4AIxIx1AByOfPAjjAZW4xXUJSgCm8MylUDoCNKBJWcLolBQAG0QFsdviALqnEAAEkoYEYmGKOj0hhMfgCCksCEejFIIsscAgxgdTuKnsCQUclL8LEsAA5LHFbPlpEA):

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300}},
  "data": {
    "url": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-datasets@v1.29.0/data/cars.json"
  },
  "mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 60},
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Origin", "legend": {}},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Horsepower"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "Miles_per_Gallon"}
  },
  "selection": {
    "intervalSelect": {"type": "interval"},
    "selector003": {
      "type": "multi",
      "bind": {"legend": {"type": "click", "markname": "legendMark"}},
      "fields": ["Origin"]
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json"
}
```

Comment: This configuration seems to take away the ability to shift click multiple legend items.. is there a way around that?

Comment: I found a workaround, which is to set the type to `'dblclick'` and remove markname.

Comment: Not sure whats happening with `markname` because it is just used as an unique identifier which should not affect the events functionality, so `shift+click` should be able to multiselect with or without `markname`. if `dblclick` works for you then its good, maybe someone can add more better approach to your question.